# One to many relation does not map, list is empty C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core

So I have a game and when trying to log in to the game, `Game` class should get the `Player`, but it does not. The `Player` itself gets the `Game id`. `Player` has `Many to One` relation to the game.
Using `Web APi` and `Entity Framework Core`

Game class below:

```
public class Game
{
    public ICollection<Player> players { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? startedAt { get; set; }

    public Game( DateTime createdAt, DateTime startedAt, List<Player> players)
    {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.startedAt = startedAt;
        this.players = players;
    }

    public Game()
    {
        this.players = new List<Player>();
        this.createdAt = DateTime.Now;
        this.startedAt = null;
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player p)
    {
        players.Add(p);
    }

    public Game startGame()
    {
        startedAt = DateTime.Now;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Player class:

```
public class Player : IObserver
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public int experience { get; set; }
    public int gold { get; set; }
    public Tower tower { get; set; }
    public Turret turret { get; set; }
    public Subject subject { get; set; }
    public Army army { get; set; }
    public Game game { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {

    }

    public Player(string name, int exp, int cash)
    {
        username = name;
        experience = exp;
        gold = cash;

        tower = new Tower(this);
        turret = new Turret(this);
        subject = new Subject();
    }
```

Database context class:

```
public class HavanaContext: DbContext
{
    public HavanaContext()
    {

    }
    public HavanaContext(DbContextOptions<HavanaContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Coordinates> Coordinates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tower> Towers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Turret> Turrets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fighter> Fighters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Army> Armies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
           .HasOne(p => p.tower)
           .WithOne(t => t.player)
           .HasForeignKey<Tower>(t => t.player_id)
           .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
           .HasOne(p => p.turret)
           .WithOne(t => t.player)
           .HasForeignKey<Turret>(t => t.player_id)
           .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
           .HasOne(p => p.army)
           .WithOne(a => a.player)
           .HasForeignKey<Army>(a => a.player_id)
           .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
          .HasMany<Player>(g => g.players)
          .WithOne(p => p.game);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
           .HasOne(p => p.subject)
           .WithOne(s => s.player)
           .HasForeignKey<Subject>(s => s.player_id)
           .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

It has relation between player and the game.

API calling method:

```
        static async Task<Uri> CreateGameAsync(Player player)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
        "api/games", player);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return response.Headers.Location;
    }
```

GameController:

```
[Route("api/games")]
[ApiController]
public class GameController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly HavanaContext _context;
    public int Qty { get; set; } = 0;

    public GameController(HavanaContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET api/player/5/game
    [HttpPost()]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateGame([FromBody] Player p)
    {
        if (p == null || p.game != null)
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

        var game = _context.Games.Where(x => x.startedAt == null).First();
        if (game != null)
        {
            game.addPlayer(p);
            if (game.players.Count == 2)
                game.startGame();
            p.game = game;
            _context.Games.Update(game);
        }
        else
        {
            var new_game = new Game();
            new_game.addPlayer(p);
            p.game = new_game;
            _context.Games.Update(new_game);
        }
        _context.Players.Update(p);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
}
```

When doing the log in fucntion, `player list` is always empty, it doesn't get it. Tried to change relations by the `Entity Framework` documentation but apparently it didn't work.

Additionally a screenshot of debugging process:
[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnt4w.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to use `Include` to load related entities. [Check this MS Doc article out.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#eagerly-loading) The key could be eager loading. e.g.: `_context.Games.Where(g => g.startedAt == null).Include(g => g.Players).First();`

Comment: As I am using Entity Framework Core, I don't have include option.

Comment: Sorry, EF was linked, but EF Core has `Include` too. Take a look --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading

Comment: After some work on lazy loading from the documentation you attached, it seems to get the player list on the game, but now stuck on error "Error while copying content to a stream". This happens when doing method GetAsync with lazy loader attribute.

Comment: Your example code in question contains no `GetAsync` and I guess the root issue is solved and this is a new one.